# HTML rich text editor using contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html

I have used a few rich text editors over the years (CKEditor, Yahoo UI rich editor, jQuery wysiwyg etc) and they all have one feature in common which is causing trouble for me - they use iframes instead of an inline `contentEditable` element.

Are there any editors out there that use `contentEditable`? I realize I could probably develop one from scratch that suits my particular requirements if needed, but I'd prefer if possible to rely on work that's already been done to deal with browser compatibility, resizing, etc.

The reason I'm trying to get away from iframes is they cause problems with, for example, window focus.

Comment: You can take a look at [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/). I'm not sure it's open source, but you can take a look at it.